# Why do Pyside2 QT Properties need to be class vs instance objects?

Tags: python, pyside2

I was working on getting up to speed with QT, QML and Pyside2 (Qt for Python) and found I had some issues partly because I was creating the Properties object as an instance inside `__init__()` and it was not working. Once I put it as a Class object, how the examples show me, it worked. But I am having trouble understanding exactly why.

```py
active_site_prop = Property(int, get_site_num, set_site_num, notify=site_num_changed)
```

vs

```py
    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)
        self.active_site_prop = Property(int, self.get_site_num, self.set_site_num, notify=self.site_num_changed)
```

My references

- https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Python_UsingQtProperties
- https://qmlbook.github.io/ch18-python/python.html#a-model-from-python

Answer (score 2):

You cannot implement q-properties in runtime as well as the q-signals and q-slots since in C++ you cannot do an introspection in run-time so the MOC (MetaObject Compiler) implements that introspection in compile-time. This same concept is exported by bindings, and in the case of q-properties they have a similar behavior to native properties.

Comment: Yes, that makes perfect sense. You cannot wait to create an instance and it must exist before runtime for it to work with C++. I wish some of the documentation was more explicit about some of this and not implying it as much as they. I understand once known most people would catch this, but it always helps to be reminded.

Comment: @TravisT Where in the docs is it not explicit? I have not seen any Qt docs that use Property as the error that you indicate or in some good docs like qmlbook, if there are, tell me to report the bug.

Comment: I am not sure I would call it a bug. Just assumptions of knowledge and understanding on why something is the way it is. Some of this is my own learning curve and ignorance to how the C++ wrapper is setup and expected to be used. It just seems that if it differs from how Python is typically used that it should have an explanation on why. I think that it would not be bad to have a note saying "Properties need to be defined before runtime to be able to interact with QT, which is why it needs to be a class variable"

Comment: @TravisT No, that is an error on your part, you assume that one technology has the characteristics of another and that in general is false. When you learn a new technology, don't assume anything but analyze the docs and examples as if it were the first technology on your part. Even as I pointed out in my last paragraph: Qproperties are like python properties (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property setter and getter) and those are declared in the class

Comment: Good point, it does acts very similar to Python class properties and definitely see the similarities and how it would have been better for me to think of it in that way. Properties in both cases are not instance variables. 

To be fair this is different than one technology over another, but mixing them is where the complexity is added. Often the issue with wrapping one language with another, two different structures and paradigm even if the code itself looks similar. 

Thanks again as you really did put this into perspective so I understand.